# Discover and click hyperlink

Tags: java, hyperlink, swt, swtbot

I'm trying to test by SWTBot hyperlinks inside my Eclipse's text editor. The problem is that the hyperlinks are shown on demand (an Eclipse feature), meaning - the token changes is revealed as hyperLink only when mouse moves over it + a keyboard key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>) is pressed.

How can I simulate in SWTBot the mouse-move together with a key pressed?

Answer (score -1):

When mouse moves over a link, then a `MouseEvent` is generated. Some `MouseMotionListener` (or maybe `MouseListener`) consumes this event and then shows hiperlink for you. 
You can simulate this event:

```
Component source = null; // TODO set up a valid component
    MouseEvent event = new MouseEvent(source, MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, System.currentTimeMillis(), InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK, source.getX(), source.getY(), 0, false);
    MouseMotionListener[] mouseMotionListeners = source.getMouseMotionListeners();
    if (mouseMotionListeners!= null && mouseMotionListeners.length > 0) {
        MouseMotionListener mouseMotionListener = mouseMotionListeners[0];
        mouseMotionListener.mouseMoved(event);
    }
```

The `InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK` in the constructor means that Alt is pressed.
Note that you should define what `Component` responsible for consuming events in your case.

You can find more information in the tutorial [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [MouseEvent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)

Comment: The question is about SWT and SWTBot, not Swing/AWT